# How to Dequeue an Enqueued Message?

Tags: c#, .net, activemq-classic

I've been working on sending and receiving ActiveMQ messages between .net applications and everything work great when there is a active Consumer Connection.

However there are scenarios that I won't be able to have a active Consumer, example: web application consuming active messages.

I notice that any message not delivered to a consumer is place in a "Messages Enqueued" bucket.

Is there a way I can consume an already send and Enqueued message for a particular topic?

I am workign with Topic only, as shown on the example below

any tips from .net or even java might help me out thanks[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Topics (except for durable topics) are inherently going to throw messages away if you don't have a consumer connected at the time the message is sent. That's just how topics work. My guess is that the web UI's column header is misleading- it probably should say "messages sent". You cannot retrieve them.

More on durable topics and queues here: http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-durable-queues-and-topics-work.html

Comment: I understand it now, not sure how I am goign to solve consuming it from web then.. I don't want to create a new layer of comunication between a web and a durable connection without using activemq just because of this issue

Comment: Generally (as a pattern) you don't want to consume messages from a web server, other than to trigger a lookup against a persistent store (eg a database). Your instinct to avoid persisting data for longer periods on the MQ server is a good one.